Sufficient conditions on immersion $S^1\sqcup\ldots \sqcup S^1\to \mathbb{R}^2$ to guarantee a finite number of multiple points.
Denote the disjoint union of $n$ copies of $S^1$ as
$$\mathbb{S}^n := \underbrace{S^1\sqcup\ldots \sqcup S^1}_{n}.$$
Let $\mathcal{L}:\mathbb{S}^n\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth embedding (i.e. a tame link), $\pi_P:\mathbb{R}^3\to P$ the orthogonal projection onto a plane $P\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, and $\iota_P:P\to\mathbb{R}^2$ an isometry.
Let $\ell:\mathbb{S}^n\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be the composition of these three maps
$$\ell = \iota_P\circ\pi_P\circ\mathcal{L}.$$
We say that $\ell$ is a regular link projection if:

$\ell$ is an immersion.
$\ell$ cuts itself transverselly, i.e., if $\ell(p) = \ell(q)$ then the vectors $\ell'(p)$ and $\ell'(q)$ span $\mathbb{R}^2$.
$\ell$ has no $k$-tuple points for $k > 2$, i.e., $|\ell^{-1}(\{(x,y)\})| \leq 2$ for all $(x,y)\in \ell(\mathbb{S}^n)$.

Can we guarantee that the number of double points of a regular link projection is finite?
I have a sketch of a proof but it contains several gaps.
My intuition tells me that conditions 1 and 2 mean that the set of double points is countable and nowhere dense (why?). Which means that if there are infinitely many double points, then one of the copies of $S^1$ must contain an infinite amount of them. Consider that copy of $S^1$, a point in it that is not double and an orientation. Starting with that point and moving along it via that orientation, we produce a sequence of double points $\{p_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. This sequence is Cauchy (why?) so it has a limit $p$ in the compact set $S^1$. Since $\ell$ is a continuous map on a compact set, then its image must be itself also compact. Then $p$ must also be a double point (why?). But one can construct a subsequence of $\{p_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that its image under $\ell'$ does not converge to a non-zero vector (how?), which would contradict one or more of the conditions imposed on $\ell$ (which?).
